# Cython anomalous speed differences when casting variable from float to short?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I've noticed that when attempting to optimize a Cython loop, casting a float to a short take significantly more time for a defined (and ctyped) variable. Here is an example function with OPTION 1 and OPTION 2 denoted, one of which will be commented out when comparing the performance:

```
cpdef np.ndarray[np.int16_t, ndim=2] test_func(short[:, :, :] data_array):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, k, n
    cdef Py_ssize_t n_pts = data_array.shape[0], length = data_array.shape[1], width = data_array.shape[2]
    cdef float x_diff, y_diff, xy_sum

    coeffs_array = np.zeros((length, width), dtype=np.int16)
    cdef short[:, :] coeffs = coeffs_array

    for i in range(length):
        for k in range(width):
            xy_sum = 0
            for n in range(n_pts):
                x_diff = data_array[n, i, k]
                y_diff = data_array[n, 0, 0]
                xy_sum = xy_sum + (x_diff * y_diff)

            # OPTION 1
            coeffs[i, k] = <short> xy_sum
            # OPTION 2
            coeffs[i, k] = <short> (7.235 + 2.31 + 78.123)

    return coeffs_array
```

After compiling with one of the two options active, I tested with the following:

```
import numpy as np
from gen_libs.test import test_func
import time
np.random.seed(0)
jn = np.random.choice(100, size=(500, 5000, 500)).astype(np.int16)
start_time = time.time()
a = test_func(jn)
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

The performance of the two options changes drastically:

**OPTION 1:** `1.5317 seconds`

**OPTION 2:** `0.0025 seconds`

What am I missing here? It seems that `xy_sum` should be a simple ctyped float, just like the sum of the decimal numbers. I tested again by defining a new float variable like so:

```
cdef float a

a = (7.235 + 2.31 + 78.123)
coeffs[i, k] = <short> a
```

But again the timing was `0.0026 seconds`, so what is it about `xy_sum` that is causing this ~1,000x slowdown? Is there something connected to the array access of `x_diff` and `y_diff` that could be an issue? I'm stumped.

**EDIT:**

Here's a test that appears to narrow it down to whether or not the variable getting cast from float to short was accumulative or not. No idea why this would make any difference:

Accumulative (`xy_sum += x_diff`)

```
cpdef np.ndarray[np.int16_t, ndim=2] test_func(short[:, :, :] data_array):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, k, n
    cdef Py_ssize_t n_pts = data_array.shape[0], length = data_array.shape[1], width = data_array.shape[2]
    cdef float x_diff, y_diff, xy_sum, a

    coeffs_array = np.zeros((length, width), dtype=np.int16)
    cdef short[:, :] coeffs = coeffs_array

    for i in range(length):
        for k in range(width):
            xy_sum = 0
            for n in range(n_pts):
                x_diff = 0.152
                # XY_SUM ACCUMULATING
                xy_sum += x_diff
            coeffs[i, k] = <short> xy_sum

    return coeffs_array
```

Time: `1.068 seconds`

Non-accumulative (`xy_sum = x_diff`)

```
cpdef np.ndarray[np.int16_t, ndim=2] test_func(short[:, :, :] data_array):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, k, n
    cdef Py_ssize_t n_pts = data_array.shape[0], length = data_array.shape[1], width = data_array.shape[2]
    cdef float x_diff, y_diff, xy_sum, a

    coeffs_array = np.zeros((length, width), dtype=np.int16)
    cdef short[:, :] coeffs = coeffs_array

    for i in range(length):
        for k in range(width):
            xy_sum = 0
            for n in range(n_pts):
                x_diff = 0.152
                # XY_SUM NON-ACCUMULATING
                xy_sum = x_diff
            coeffs[i, k] = <short> xy_sum

    return coeffs_array
```

Time: `0.0025 seconds`

Comment: `<short> (7.235 + 2.31 + 78.123)` is a constant value, so it will probably be precalculated at compile time and turn into a simple assignment. Converting a `float` variable to a `short` requires runtime overhead

Comment: Probably, but I tried the following as well: `a = i / (k + 1)` and then `coeffs[i, k] = <short> a` so it can't be precalculated (I assume) and though there's a slowdown, it's now `0.0042 seconds`, so maybe a factor of 2, but not the 1000x slowdown that I'm seeing.

Comment: Regarding the findings in your edit: It may be that the optimizer is aggressive enough to figure out whether the innermost loop actually has an effect or whether it can be safely removed. In the `xy_sum = x_diff` version it might be able to tell that the value of `xy_sum` won't change no matter how many times it would iterate, so it just removes the loop

Comment: Ah, I think you're right. It's finding ways to drop the inner loop, which is repeated about the same number of times as the slowdown multiple.